# Iterate over Python list with clear code - rewriting functions

Tags: python

I've followed a tutorial to write a Flask REST API and have a special request about a Python code.

The offered code is following:

```py
# data list is where my objects are stored 
def put_one(name):
    list_by_id = [list for list in data_list if list['name'] == name]
    list_by_id[0]['name'] = [new_name] 
    print({'list_by_id' : list_by_id[0]})
```

It works, which is nice, and even though I understand what line 2 is doing, I would like to rewrite it in a way that it's clear how the function iterates over the different lists. I already have an approach but it returns `Key Error: 0`

```py
def put(name):    
    list_by_id = []
    list = []
    for list in data_list:
        if(list['name'] == name):
            list_by_id = list
            list_by_id[0]['name'] = request.json['name'] 
    return jsonify({'list_by_id' : list_by_id[0]})
```

My goal with this is also to be able to put other elements, that don't necessarily have the type `'name'`. If I get to rewrite the function in an other way I'll be more likely to adapt it to my needs.

I've looked for tools to convert one way of coding into the other and answers in forums before coming here and couldn't find it.

Comment: `list_by_id = list` doesn't create a list. There is no 0 element.

Comment: In your rewrite nothing ever gets put into `list_by_id` (which isn't a great name as it's not clear in what sense the items in that are "by ID" - by _name_, maybe?), so `list_by_id[0]` would always be an index (_not_ key) error. But it seems like what you actually want is just the _first_ thing of that name from `data_list`, in which case that's `next(list for list in data_list if list['name'] == name)` (although the naming's still not great as `list['name']` suggests the "list" is a _dictionary_ or other mapping).

Comment: *"I would like to rewrite it in a way that it's clear how the function iterates over the different lists"* — It's already fairly clear in the first version…?!

Comment: Oh no wait, I see why it's a _key_ error - `list_by_id = list` overwrites the empty list (which _was_ a list) with `list` (which isn't). Neither `list_by_id = []` nor `list = []` actually gets used, and the latter initialises to a value that's not the same type that it will get as the loop variable, which is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be beatiful code, but it gets the job done:

```py
    def put(value):
        for i in range(len(data_list)):
            key_list = list(data_list[i].keys())
            if data_list[i][key_list[0]] == value:
                print(f"old value: {key_list[0], data_list[i][key_list[0]]}")
                data_list[i][key_list[0]] = request.json[test_key]
                print(f"new value: {key_list[0], data_list[i][key_list[0]]}")
                break
```

Now it doesn't matter what the `key` value is, with this iteration the method will only change the value when it finds in the `data_list`. Before the code breaked at every iteration cause the **keys** were different and they played a role.